# WordPress REST API function not calling from external site

Tags: rest-api

I have create custom end point using jwt authentication method the function workin from post man api but not from site which defines

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function ($data) {
    register_rest_route( 'jwt-auth/v1', 'certificates', array(
       'methods' => 'POST', 
        'callback' => 'update_payment_history',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true' 
    ) );  
  });
```